# Why doesn't BroadcastStream implement stream

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, actix-web

I'm writing an HTTP server in the `actix_web` framework using the `tokio` runtime and `tokio-stream` utilities. I would like to send some data ([`actix::web::Bytes`](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/web/struct.Bytes.html)) from a [`broadcast`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/broadcast/index.html) channel in a response. I also want to do some other stuff, so I'd like to write a wrapper implementing the [`MessageBody`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/body/trait.MessageBody.html) trait that at some point forwards the `.poll_next()` method. The problematic code looks like this:

```
use actix_web::web::Bytes;
use actix_web::body::{BodyStream, MessageBody};
use tokio_stream::wrappers::BroadcastStream;
use futures_core::stream::Stream;
// ...

struct Wrapper {
    // some other stuff
    broad_rx: BodyStream<BroadcastStream<broadcast::Receiver<Bytes>>>
}
impl MessageBody for Wrapper {
    type Error = BroadcastStreamRecvError;

    fn size(&self) -> actix_web::body::BodySize {
        BodySize::Stream
    }

    fn poll_next(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> std::task::Poll<Option<Result<Bytes, Self::Error>>> {
        /*
        do some other stuff
        */

        self.broad_rx.poll_next(cx) // XXX the problem
    }
}
```

This snippet doesn't compile and returns the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `poll_next` found for struct `BodyStream` in the current scope
   --> crates/demo/src/server.rs:***:***
    |
*** |         self.broad_rx.poll_next(cx)
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `BodyStream<BroadcastStream<tokio::sync::broadcast::Receiver<actix_web::web::Bytes>>>`
```

I expect `BodyStream` to implement `MessageBody` and thus the `.poll_next()` method. because of [this impl](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/body/struct.BodyStream.html#impl-MessageBody) and the following chain of implementations:

`Bytes` implements:

1. [`Clone`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Bytes.html#impl-Clone)
2. [`Send`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Bytes.html#impl-Send)
3. I'm not sure how to deduce whether it has a `'static` lifetime in this context, as it's not a reference. If the lifetime isn't `'static` I'd assume that is the problem, but I also don't know how to solve it. However, I'd also assume that the compiler would mention something about lifetimes if that is the case.

`BroadcastStream<Bytes>` implements:

1. [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/0.1.8/tokio_stream/wrappers/struct.BroadcastStream.html#impl-Stream), if `Bytes` is `'static + Clone + Send`. `Item = Result<Bytes, BroadcastStreamRecvError>` in that case.

`BroadcastStreamRecvError` implements:

1. [`Error`](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/0.1.8/tokio_stream/wrappers/errors/enum.BroadcastStreamRecvError.html#impl-Error) and via [this blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CE%3E) presumably also `Into<Box<dyn Error + 'static, Global>>`

`BodyStream<Bytes>` implements:

1. [`MessageBody`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/body/struct.BodyStream.html#impl-MessageBody) because the `Stream` bound is satisfied by `BroadcastStream<Bytes>` and the `'static + Into<Box<dyn Error + 'static, Global>>` is satisfied by
   `BroadcastStreamRecvError` (except those pesky `'static` requirements again)

Yet the error suggests, that one of the implementations doesn't apply for whatever reason. In fact even if I replace

```
broad_rx: BodyStream<BroadcastStream<broadcast::Receiver<Bytes>>>
```

with

```
broad_rx: BroadcastStream<broadcast::Receiver<Bytes>>
```

I still get an error saying that the `.poll_next()` method doesn't exist, despite the fact that this type should implement `Stream`.

How can I implement the `MessageBody` wrapper or further debug this?

Comment: Just a hunch, but [`Stream::poll_next`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#tymethod.poll_next) doesn't take in `Self`, it takes in `Pin<&mut Self>`. Try pinning `&mut self.broad_rx` and calling `poll_next()` on that.

Comment: Thank you @kmdreko. It seems obvious now, but this was indeed one of the problems. I brushed up on the contents of the async rust book, and with the help of the `pin-project` crate, I resolved the aforementioned error. The code still doesn't compile due to the complicated trait bounds, but that's probably a story for another question.

Answer (score 3):

The presented code has three problems preventing it from being compiled. The one causing the given error is caused by the problem put forth by @kmdreko. The reason why `Pin` is needed is a bit complicated and can be found in the [`async rust book`](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/04_pinning/01_chapter.html). In a superficial way: If you want to use a `.poll` method then the thing needs to be pinned. One of the ways to solve this problem is using the `pin-project` crate that simplifies the creation of *projections* (helper functions used to access fields of pinned structs). Otherwise, one can write their own projections manually, like in [`this article`](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/pin-and-suffering).

The declaration then looks like this:

```rust
#[pin_project]
struct Wrapper {
    #[pin]
    broad_rx: BroadcastStream<broadcast::Receiver<Bytes>>,
}
```

and the projection that presents the pinned field (see further below) can be obtained like so:

```rust
let this = self.project();
```

This still doesn't compile, but for a trivial reason. First of all, the `BodyStream` is not needed at all, because the `MessageBody` is being manually implemented anyway. Secondly, the generic type of `BroadcastStream` isn't supposed to be the wrapped type (also because the wrapped type will always be `broadcast::Receiver<_>`), but the type returned from the channel. The following code compiles:

```rust
struct Wrapper {
    broad_rx: BroadcastStream<Bytes>
}
impl MessageBody for Wrapper {
    type Error = BroadcastStreamRecvError;

    fn size(&self) -> actix_web::body::BodySize {
        BodySize::Stream
    }

    fn poll_next(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> std::task::Poll<Option<Result<Bytes, Self::Error>>> {
        let this = self.project();
        this.broad_rx.poll_next(cx)
    }
}
```